# out of memory error occurs

Tags: java, linked-list, out-of-memory

Below code is to implement singly linked list(From one of leetcode problems). In this case, I wanted to show all elements in the linked list, for example, [1, 2, 3, 4]. But the below message comes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.linkedlist.ch4.ListNode.display(leetcode_linkedlist.java:33)
    at com.linkedlist.ch4.leetcode_linkedlist.main(leetcode_linkedlist.java:51)
```

One problem I am guessing is whenever the display() method is invoked the object "this" is not created at the time. Any solution ? I do not want this method to be a no argument method. Thanks.

```
package com.linkedlist.ch4; 
//Definition for singly-linked list.



class ListNode {
int val;
ListNode next;  
ListNode(int x) {
    val = x;
}

public String toString(){

    return ""+val ;
}

public void display(){
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
    str.append("[ ");
    while(true){

        ListNode start = this;
        String val = start.val+"";
        str = str.append(val);
        start = start.next;
        if(start == null){
            str.append(" ]");
            break;
        }

        str = str.append(", ");
    }

    System.out.println(str.toString());

   }
}

public class leetcode_linkedlist {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ListNode node1 = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode node2 = new ListNode(2);
    ListNode node3 = new ListNode(3);
    ListNode node4 = new ListNode(4);
    node1.next = node2;
    node2.next = node3;
    node3.next = node4;

    node1.display();

    System.out.println("------------");
    System.out.println("------------");

    deleteNode(node1);

    node1.display();

  }
public static void deleteNode(ListNode node) {
        if(node == null) return;
        node.val = node.next.val;
        node.next = node.next.next;
    }



}
```

Comment: why do you need to display in the first place?

Comment: then your loop is probably never terminating.  Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: "this" will be there for sure.

Comment: @OldProgrammer : yes, the loop never ended. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the *first* node to the string, over and over again, until it runs out of memory to store the string:

```
while(true){
    ListNode start = this;
    // 'start' now refers to the first node (the one you called the method on)

    String val = start.val+"";
    str = str.append(val);
    // the node 'start' is added to the current string

    start = start.next;
    // 'start' now refers to the second node

    if(start == null){
        str.append(" ]");
        break;
    }
    // since the second node exists, don't exit the loop.

    str = str.append(", ");
}
```

You probably want to move `ListNode start = this;` to just before the loop. That way, it won't reset `start` to the first node each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

It is an infinite loop, `this` will always be pointing to the first node and hence `ListNode start = this;` will always be pointing to the same node.
You just need to iterate properly

```
ListNode current = this;
while(current!=null){
 ... construct string 
 current = current.next
}
```

Your guess: *the `this` wasn't created*. Is totally wrong because the `this` reference will always be there if an object is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks. yes this reference will be there.